# windows 10 bash tcpdump: socket: Invalid argument

Tags: networking, tcpdump, windows-subsystem-for-linux, network-tools

I am using windows 10 bash to use tcpdump
From tutorial i found that to listen to a interface command is:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 //eth0 is ethernet interface
tcpdump -i any // to listen to any interface
```

In both cases I am getting tcpdump: socket: Invalid argument error.
NOTE:

```
tcpdump -D
```

does not print anything on console.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/69, this is a limitation of the current Windows Subsystem for Linux.  The Fall Creators update added a lot of functionality, but tcpdump still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try `nmap`.  It will output a page of errors but eventually works.

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

WSL, while utilizing Linux, is not a "true" Linux based operating system yet.

Comment: I fail to see how this answer is relevant to the question?